# Error Verifying smart contract on EtherScan using Hardhat

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, openzeppelin, hardhat

Below is my smart contract (already deployed). When i try and verify it to submit the code to Etherscan I am getting the error below and I really don't know why.  Please can someone advise?

```
 npx hardhat verify --network ropsten 0xE9abA803d6a801fce021d0074ae71256C9F24Da4
```

Error Message:

```
 Error in plugin @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan: More than one contract was found to match the deployed bytecode.
 Please use the contract parameter with one of the following contracts:
 * @openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol:PaymentSplitter
  * contracts/MyNFTContract.sol: MyNFTContract

 For example:

   hardhat verify --contract contracts/Example.sol:ExampleContract <other args>

 If you are running the verify subtask from within Hardhat instead:

   await run("verify:verify", {
     <other args>,
     contract: "contracts/Example.sol:ExampleContract"
  };
```

MyNFTContract.sol:

```
 // SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

 import "@openzeppelin/contracts/finance/PaymentSplitter.sol";

 contract MyNFTContract is PaymentSplitter {
     // Addresses of payees
     address[] private _CSPayees = [
         0x23377d974d85C49E9CB6cfdF4e0EED1C0Fc85E6A,
         0x85F68F10d3c13867FD36f2a353eeD56533f1C751
     ];
     // Number of shares allocated per address in this contract.  In same order as _CSPayees
     uint256[] private _CSShares = [1, 2];

     constructor() PaymentSplitter(_CSPayees, _CSShares) {}
 }
```

My deploying script deploy.js:

```
 async function main() {
const PaymentSplitter = await ethers.getContractFactory("MyNFTContract")

// Start deployment, returning a promise that resolves to a contract object
const myNFT = await PaymentSplitter.deploy()
console.log("Contract deployed to address:", myNFT.address)
 }

 main()
.then(() => process.exit(0))
.catch((error) => {
    console.error(error)
    process.exit(1)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imported these

```
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle");
require("@nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan");
```

and it worked

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 13):

Hardhat found multiple contracts in the project (your `MyNFTContract` and the imported `PaymentSplitter`), and it doesn't know against which one you want to verify the bytecode.

You need to specify the contract (that you want to verify) with the `--contract` option.

```
npx hardhat verify \
--contract "contracts/MyNFTContract.sol" \
--network ropsten 0xE9abA803d6a801fce021d0074ae71256C9F24Da4
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message that you are encountering is because hardhat found multiple contracts in your contract file; so, you have to specify which contract you want to verify to specify that you can add contract to you run:

```
await run("verify:verify", {
      address: contractAddress,
      constructorArguments: args,
      contract: "contracts/OurToken.sol:OurToken"
    }
```